# Does Instagram Selection of Image Effect uses Modal View?

Tags: iphone, view, modal-dialog, instagram

I'm trying to make a similar effect where only a part or 1/8 of the page is being occupied by a view controller. Do you guys have done something like this before?

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image effect selection in Instagram is probably just a UIScrollView of buttons. It is not a full Modal Viewcontroller.